# SEMANTICKEYPHRASETABLE did not work with Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I created a table and followed all the steps shown in [this link](http://[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509085.aspx][1]). But it seems that it did not work with excel files. Do not know why or any document explain why?

Comment: link you attached is not showing content

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509109.aspx

Comment: Is someone helping the issue?